# Appcelerator - multiple apps same codebase

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I would like to create an iOS app using appcelerator, and from it create multiple forks, each fork having a few differences, like colors, logos, etc.
A config file can sort out the differences, this and different results that could come from the API.

But can I have the same codebase for multiple apps?
In native Android, you'd use Gradle and product flavours?
What options are there in Appcelerator?

Down the line, these apps will need to be updated. Ideally, only the "core" app should be updated and all forks will pickup differences. But how could this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have one app with multiple Alloy Themes, and set the theme that you want before you build a version of your app, to set the theme, you add the line "theme":"yourTheme3" at the "global" property of app/config.json

Your themes will be placed in e.g. app/themes/yourTheme7

Each theme also have a config.json to set specific properties, you can have specific assets, controllers, views, etc...

You can get the value of a property of the config.json like this:

```
Alloy.CFG.yourProperty
```

There are some things that you have to do manually:

- [Change DefaultIcon for iOS apps](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1318)
- Change the id or name of your app (tiapp.xml) or use this: [TiCh(ange)- change TiApp.xml properties via the CLI for building multiple apps from one codebase](https://github.com/jasonkneen/TiCh)

Check out this page of the documentation for Alloy Themes: 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes

Answer (score 1):

With "fork" you mean git forks? If so it just depends on your file structure. You could create a CommonJS file with the core and require it in your controllers. Then inside your forks you make your adjustments. After a while when you want to change something on your core you make another branch and merge it in all of your forks.

Comment: Yes, git will be used. Thinking about it, I could have just a single codebase with multiple local clones. These local clones do not need to be versioned, they're used only for build and send to app store.

Comment: The differences between versions can be maintained using http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes - Multiple themes present in the codebase and then each local clone will use one theme